# Copy specific files from one directory to another appending it's base directory name

Tags: python, linux, bash, find, xargs

I have
 ~/a/a1/1.pdf 
~/a/a1/2.pdf 
~/a/b1/1.pdf 
~/a/b1/2.pdf 
I want to copy all the pdfs into ~/a/c with names a1_1.pdf,a1_2.pdf,b1_1.pdf,b2_2.pdf. How do I do that?

Please forgive my ignorance.I am new to programming and linux

Comment: what are all the ways that you have tried and what's failing you from doing this?

Comment: I won't do it for you because you'll learn more by doing it. But have a look at the os module and the methods that strings have (e.g. strip, split, toupper etc).

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are not familiar with Linux. Below is how to do it shell commands.  Once this is understood, if you want to do it from within a Python script, you can do similar actions with an import of the os module.

First make your target directory:

```
# mkdir ~/a
# mkdir ~/a/c
```

then you can copy

```
# cp ~/a/a1/1.pdf ~a/c/a1_1.pdf
# cp ~/a/a1/2.pdf ~a/c/a1_2.pdf
# cp ~/a/b1/2.pdf ~a/c/b1_1.pdf
# cp ~/a/b1/2.pdf ~a/c/b2_2.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you need to automatically browse folders, so if you need it you can use something like this to identify PDF files:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(~/a):
    print(root, dirs, files)
```

Then you can manipulate path with [*os.path* commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html):

```
os.path.dirname('~/a/a1/1.pdf') -> '~/a/a1'
os.path.basename('~/a/a1/1.pdf') -> '1.pdf'
```

Finally you can also use [shutil.copyfile command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile):

```
shutil.copy('~/a/a1/1.pdf', '~/c/a1_1.pdf')
```

I let you combine and test all these commands so that you get familiar with python. Don't hesitate to print or debug variables before doing the final *shutil.copyfile*